# PowerPoint - propagate changes when using duplicate slide

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

In PowerPoint (any of the editions) there is an option called "duplicate slide" that simply creates an exact copy of one slide. This can be useful when you want to have some common elements in a slide or when you have a list and want to show the items of such list progressively.

The problem with this function is that if you change anything in the "master" slide, these changes are not propagated to the duplicated slides. Is there a function to link the duplicated slides to the "master" slide so if for example the title of this slide is changed it will also be changed in the other slides? I have seen similar functions in other software, I am surprised something like this is not available in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint doesn't have this feature.  An odd sort of workaround you might try is:

Go to slide sorter view, select the "master" slide and CTRL+C to copy it.

Add a new blank slide, do Home | click triangle beneath Paste | Paste Special and choose Microsoft PowerPoint Slide Object and click Paste Link. Click OK.

[image: Paste Special Screenshot]

Adjust the pasted slide object to fill the slide.

The pasted slide object may not update as soon as you change the "master" slide but seems to do so on saving the presentation. You can also right-click it and select Update Link to force an update.

Note:  if the Paste Special dialog box only gives a Slide option, it's because the thumbnail pane on the left is active; dismiss the dialog, click on the new blank slide and try again.

Comment: Added a screenshot for clarity and added the Update Link option you get on right-click. Thanks for sharing this, I didn't expect I'd ever seriously use Paste Link for anything. This works well with the unfortunate side-effect of *slightly* impacting the font weight on the linked slide in my case.

Comment: One other issue I just noticed: these are absolute and not relative links. If you rename your slide the link will break. if you version your slides the links will point to older versions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to use the ZOOM SLIDE option.

1. Create a "blank" slide
2. Use the drag-drop to get a smallish linked object into the new slide
3. Expand the zoom object to fill the whole "blank" slide

Any changes to the original slide will now immediately show up in the zoom slide !